# How to insert BLOB data from file with Bookshelf.js with node.js?

Tags: node.js, blob, bookshelf.js, multer

I am handling file uploads, using multer, in node.js.  I need to store the file data in a blob field in a table.  Is there a way to bind a file pointer to Bookshelf.js?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while but here is the answer to your question. Maybe it can help someone else in the future.

```
        let err = validateFiles(req.files, constants.MAX_FILES, constants.MAX_WEIGHT_PER_FILE, constants.VALID_FILE_EXTENSIONS);
        if(err == "" && req.files){
            let fs = require('fs');
            for(const file of req.files){
                await fs.open(file.path, 'r', function (status, fd) {
                    if (status) {
                        console.log(status.message);
                        return;
                    }
                    let buffer = new Buffer(file.size);
                    fs.read(fd, buffer, 0, file.size, 0, function (err, num) {
                        let UploadFile = models.Document.forge(
                        {
                            'id': null, 
                            'Name': file.originalname, 
                            'Type': file.mimetype, 
                            'Weight': file.size, 
                            'Blob': buffer
                        }).save();
                    });
                });
            }
        }
```